# Структура сегментов в адресном пространстве процесса

Tags: память, процесс

```
|----------------------------Kernel Space------------------------------|  0xFFFFFF                                                                  
|                                                                      |
|                                                                      |
|                                                                      |
|↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓Stack↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓|
|                                                                      |
|                                                                      |
|                                                                      |
|↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓Memory mapping segment↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓|
|                                                                      |
|                                                                      |
|                                                                      |
|↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑Heap↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑|
|                                                                      |
|                                                                      |
|-----------------------------BSS  segment-----------------------------|
|-----------------------------Data segment-----------------------------|
|-----------------------------Text segment-----------------------------|
|                                                                      |
|---------------------------------OS-----------------------------------|
|________________________________BIOS__________________________________| 0x000000
```

Вопросы:

1) Как устроен `Memory mapping segment`?

2) Есть ли сегмент для констант?

3) В С++ есть и `Heap` и `Free Store`, или `Heap` интерпретируется как `Free Store` (если да, то как размещен?) ?

4) Есть сегменты(с показанных выше) которые могут отсутствовать?

5) Есть замечания к указанной структуре памяти?

Comment: memory mapping устроен в зависимости от используемого процессора. в общем виде можно ознакомится вбив в гугле например "страничное преобразование x86". Только имейте ввиду, что даже у этого одного вида процессоров, в зависимости от режимов работы может применяться 6 немного разных механизмов. И стоит помнить, что показанное на вашей картинке очень условно. Сегменты могут располагаться в памяти совершенно по разному, в зависимости от используемой ОС. А адреса справа на картинке вообще смысла не имеют. Сегмент констант не требуется, так как константы зашиты в самих командах.

Comment: Замечание только одно - нарисованная структура имеет мало общего с реальность. А в С++ нет ни heap, ни free store (точнее они никак не задают структуру программы в памяти).

Comment: хотя под memory mapping вполне возможно в данном случае понимаются не таблицы страниц, а файлы отраженные на память. Вам бы следовало уточнить что вы под этим понимаете

Comment: 2) константы, как правило, располагаются в data-сегменте 5) сегменты не обязательно располагаются в таком порядке. Кучи, стэки, дата, текст могут быть в любом порядке. Насколько знаю, их распределяет сама ос

Comment: @Александр В data все глобальные переменные. Как изменяемые, с заданными начальными значениями, так и большие константные структуры. Константы занимающие менее 8 байт (размер в зависимости от архитектуры, конечно) там не хранятся, если не требуются указатели на них

Answer (score 4):

Константы обычно размещаются в текстовом сегменте, т.к. он защищен от записи.

В остальном картинка условно соответствует большинству реализаций с виртуальной памятью. Также следует иметь в виду, что между показанными сегментами возможны "дыры" (в смысле пространства виртуальных адресов).

Распределение памяти для конкретных Linux программ на практике можно посмотреть в файле [/proc/{PID}/maps](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)

В качестве примера, вот такая программка и результат ее выполнения:

```
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ cat t-maps.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static int data = 22;

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  const char *p = "xaxa-xaxaxaxax";

  printf("main: %p  p: %p  &p: %p  &data: %p\n",
     main, p, &p, &data);
  char str[100];
  sprintf(str, "cat /proc/%d/maps", (int)getpid());
  system(str);
}
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ g++ t-maps.c && ./a.out
main: 0x56352bf8278a  p: 0x56352bf828b8  &p: 0x7ffff853a718  &data: 0x56352c183010
56352bf82000-56352bf83000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1179691                    /home/avp/hashcode/a.out
56352c182000-56352c183000 r--p 00000000 08:01 1179691                    /home/avp/hashcode/a.out
56352c183000-56352c184000 rw-p 00001000 08:01 1179691                    /home/avp/hashcode/a.out
56352ce80000-56352cea1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [heap]
7fd21e33c000-7fd21e356000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2159140                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.27.so
7fd21e356000-7fd21e555000 ---p 0001a000 08:01 2159140                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.27.so
7fd21e555000-7fd21e556000 r--p 00019000 08:01 2159140                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.27.so
7fd21e556000-7fd21e557000 rw-p 0001a000 08:01 2159140                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.27.so
7fd21e557000-7fd21e55b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fd21e55b000-7fd21e55e000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2159128                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.27.so
7fd21e55e000-7fd21e75d000 ---p 00003000 08:01 2159128                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.27.so
7fd21e75d000-7fd21e75e000 r--p 00002000 08:01 2159128                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.27.so
7fd21e75e000-7fd21e75f000 rw-p 00003000 08:01 2159128                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.27.so
7fd21e75f000-7fd21e946000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2159125                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.27.so
7fd21e946000-7fd21eb46000 ---p 001e7000 08:01 2159125                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.27.so
7fd21eb46000-7fd21eb4a000 r--p 001e7000 08:01 2159125                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.27.so
7fd21eb4a000-7fd21eb4c000 rw-p 001eb000 08:01 2159125                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.27.so
7fd21eb4c000-7fd21eb50000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fd21eb50000-7fd21eb56000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3670234                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0
7fd21eb56000-7fd21ed55000 ---p 00006000 08:01 3670234                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0
7fd21ed55000-7fd21ed56000 r--p 00005000 08:01 3670234                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0
7fd21ed56000-7fd21ed57000 rw-p 00006000 08:01 3670234                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0
7fd21ed57000-7fd21ed7e000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2159121                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.27.so
7fd21ef5a000-7fd21ef5e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fd21ef7e000-7fd21ef7f000 r--p 00027000 08:01 2159121                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.27.so
7fd21ef7f000-7fd21ef80000 rw-p 00028000 08:01 2159121                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.27.so
7fd21ef80000-7fd21ef81000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffff851c000-7ffff853d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7ffff8563000-7ffff8566000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7ffff8566000-7ffff8568000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$
```